# Why is the view model null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, null

I have the following structure:

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult PageMain(string param)
{
    return View();
}
```

PageMain.cs

```
namespace project1.Models
{
    public class PageMain
    {
        public DataTable dtable
        { 
             get {
                       // some code that returns a DataTable
             }
        }
     }
}
```

and finally in the view:

```
@using project1.Models
@model PageMain

var datatable = Model.dtable // but this is throwing an error since the model is null
```

Does anyone know why my model is returning null? How can I access the datatable in the PageMain.cs? I am new to MVC so if I have any logical error in the structure please do not hesitate in warning me :)

Comment: will this DataTable be unique per call, or it's something like a static value that you need to get access to?

Comment: it's content is designed according to the url parameter

Comment: BTW, that code belongs in the controller, not the model.

Comment: @SLaks, I'd be glad if you can explain why, I'd like to know :)

Comment: The controller is supposed to do all of the work; the model only exists to transfer data to & from the controller.  The model should not have much real code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you need to set your logic to reach the database form your model. You could use ORM to achieve that.

Then, pass your model to view from your controller. Assume that you have your person model like below:

```
public class Person {

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string SurName {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}

}
```

In order to view specific `Person` data, you need to query your model and pass this model from you controller to your view:

```
public ActionResult Index() {

  var _entities = new MyDataEntity();
  var model = _entities.Person;
  model = model.Where(x => x.Age > 20);

  return View(model);

}
```

The above controller is passing List of Person to your view. `MyDataEntity` class is your entity framework `DataContext` class.

After that you need to put `@model IEnumerable<Person>` inside your model. Here is an example:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Person>

<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model){

  <li>Name : @item.Name</li>
  <li>Surname : @item.Surname</li>
  <li>Age : @item.Age</li>

}

</ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a model in your controller to pass to the `View()`.

Comment: ahh, I thought that whenever I leave the return View() empty it was handling it automatically. I guess I was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
public ActionResult PageMain(string param)
{
    return View(new PageMain());
}
```

Comment: yes but still, now my datatable is returning null. How can I use the datatable in the PageMain.cs from the view?

Comment: @Shaokan, Would need to the see the dtable getter code to figure that out.

Comment: ahh, it's ok I've figured it out, actually I can get the dtable but it was returning null due to a code error :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a simple answer, but this is all I needed to see. I was forgetting to pass the model. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I forgot the "name" attribute for my form fields. D'OH!