# Cannot Use LINQ-Method In Razor View ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, model

I call a model in view.cshtml like this:

`@model IEnumerable<Spiirit_Project.Models.Deliverable>`

Then I use this LINQ-method in view.cshtml so:

`@{ var a = Model.Where(p => p.deliverable_research_year_id == 169).Count(); }`

When I run my project, there is error: 
"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source".

my "Deliverable" Table is not null but I get this error. How to fix this error?

there is my controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateDeliverable(int? idResearch, int? idBaseline, int? idYear){
ViewBag.IdResearch = idResearch;
ViewBag.IdBaseline = idBaseline;
ViewBag.IdYear = idYear;
ViewBag.Year = db.Deliverable_Research_Years.Find(idYear);
ViewBag.Deliverable = db.Deliverables.ToList();

return View();
}
```

Comment: Your model *is* null, regardless of your claim. If you want to prove us wrong, add a screenshot of the Visual Studio debugger with the value of Model.

Comment: Please add the controller code **to your question** (not in comments).

Comment: `return View(db.Deliverables.ToList());` - and no need to assign to  `ViewBag.Deliverable`. Then have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242810/why-is-the-view-model-null .

Comment: It is better to use `Model` than `ViewBag` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716953/viewbag-vs-model-in-mvc-net

Comment: Best practice is **not** `ViewBag`. Read the link I provided. If you need multiple objects, then create your own `AghnatModel` class with multiple properties (for each of things you need). Then use `@model Spiirit_Project.Models.AghnatModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mjwills tell me in comment to pass in the model to the view. So I change my controller like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateDeliverable(int? idResearch, int? idBaseline, int? idYear){
ViewBag.IdResearch = idResearch;
ViewBag.IdBaseline = idBaseline;
ViewBag.IdYear = idYear;
ViewBag.Year = db.Deliverable_Research_Years.Find(idYear);

return View(db.Deliverables.ToList());
}
```

This is work correctly!

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
@{ var a = Model?.Where(p => p.deliverable_research_year_id == 169).Count() ?? 0; }
```

This is assuming that `deliverable_research_year_id` is NOT a nullable type.

Comment: This assumes that the OP can use C# 6+ *and* it doesn't solve any kind of problems, it just hides a bug.